# How to add image/ads to the sides of main content

Tags: html, css

Let's say that I got a div called `container` that is 1000px wide and aligned to the center of the screen. I would like to add images/ads to the blank space that is left over the the left and right side of that div. It should be fixed and should not move into the `content` div if the screen is smaller but should instead disappear to the sides when zooming in on the website or having smaller screen.

I am pretty much trying to accomplish what probuilds.net did: https://i.gyazo.com/746c89429d9ca0e23016469120f2b607.jpg

How could that be done? Each side should have individual ad/image code.

Comment: There are many, many ways to do this. Please do your research and come back with a question related to your code.

Comment: You need a specific problem statement (e.g. "here's the markup I have, and the styles I used, but..."). You are simply asking us to write code for you, which will not happen.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using the `background-attachment` property and setting a background image within your css. This will allow scrolling within a 'inner div' (the body element) whilst ensuring the background image does not move whilst scrolling.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background: dimgray;
  height: 200vh;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
html {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
This is some text
```

If, instead, you wanted the left and right parts different images, you can use pseudo elements to achieve this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  background: dimgray;
  height: 200vh;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0;
}
html:before,
html:after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
}
html:before {
  left: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/300/1000);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html:after {
  right: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/1000);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
This is some text
```